# CSS height - 100% between 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS3/HTML5 Asp.NET 4.5 web application. I have the HTML and CSS the way I want it for my layout except for one issue.

The theory behind my css is the header and nav are obviously set at the top of the page, with a container with an aside and article, followed by an independent footer that I want always to be at the bottom of the page regardless of how little content there is. Everything works except that when I have the aside set to 100% height, it is 100% of the viewport height, meaning that on pages with little content, you have to scroll 260px (the combined height of the header, nav, and footer) to see it. So, to address that, I set the margins of the aside to 280px top, and 80px bottom thinking that would do the trick. It did not. So I started playing with position and clear as suggested by similar questions on SO and around the web without success.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Nathan A. Chesebro</h1>
                <h2>United States Merchant Marine</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>

        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <aside>
                Vessel data
            </aside>
            <article>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </article>
        </div>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* 
{
    margin: 0;
}
body 
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
}

form, html
{
    height: 100%;
}

header
{
    margin: 0px auto; 
    background-color: #1041a2;
    background-image: url(../Images/headerHCJ.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

nav
{
    background-image: url(../Images/nav.png);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

#content 
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
}

aside 
{
    margin: 180px 0px 80px 0px auto;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

article
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-left: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    height:80px;
    background: black;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? It's just a concept so I didn't copy your exact code.
Also, I am using a calc() method in the CSS (which is getting more and more browser support but may still be restrictive on some eg. opera-mini etc.).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thePav/A3NCW/1/

CSS

```
html,
body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}

header {height: 150px; background-color: #800}
  header #logo {}
  header #title {}

nav {height: 30px; background-color: #080}

#content {overflow: hidden; height: calc(100% - 280px)}
  #content aside {background-color: #555; height: 100%; float: left; width: 25%}
  #content article {float: left; width: 75%}

#footer {width: 100%; height: 100px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; background-color: #000}
```

HTML

```
<header>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="title"></div>
</header>

<nav></nav>

<div id="content">
  <aside></aside>
  <article>Some content here</article>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: YES! The calc function is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display's 'table' and 'table-cell' values.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scottmey/j9jrz/

```
#content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
aside {
    display: table-cell;
}
article {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS cannot be used to make two items the same height.

You either need to use javascript to set the height, or else use a table tag.

Comment: That's not true. You can use `display: table-cell` to display elements as table cells. It can be tricky, and it has limitations (as has table itself), but you don't need an actual html table to achieve this.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you referencing the aside and article? Because only the aside needs to be 100% height. Because article uses the default background color, its height is not really important.